How to know if chicken is cooked on charcoal bbq without temperature monitor
Is there a way to know if the chicken (bonesless on skewers, leg piece) has been done from inside too without having a temperature monitor to poke in middle of thick part of chicken.
I have noticed sometimes the chicken from outside seem grilled but inside it is raw or sometimes becomes too dry to eat. I want to maintain the juiceness of the chicken while it is cooked too, how?

If you want to cook it perfectly, get an accurate thermometer. Other than that, slicing into it allows you to peer inside, but that is not terribly accurate, nor is it desirable in some cases. However, the "cut it open" technique is, perhaps, more appropriate in a boneless, skewer situation.

I find myself eating most of bbq by that method

In a general way "doneness" of meat is mapped pretty closely to the transition from floppy-squishy raw state meat into firmer cooked meat. The trick, then (with chicken, where underdone to any extent is not good) is to figure out when it's no longer squishy all the way to the skewer and then remove it so it does not overcook and dry out. With things like beef where some level of underdone may be desired it's a finer art.
When you start, the meat is all squishy. As it starts to cook, there's a firm layer around a squishy core. When it's cooked through, it's firm to the core. If you pay attention to how it feels (in the tongs or with another tool is fine as you don't want to be prodding it with your fingers) as you're deciding to take a piece off and cut it open to check, you should be able to determine more accurately when it "feels done."
I don't claim any great skill at precisely determining how done meat is simply by prodding it, but I know professional chefs who are quite skilled at it (diners don't like someone cutting their meat open to check for most presentations, and they also don't like under or overdone .vs. what they requested.) The difference, of course, is that I have far less practice, not being a professional chef grilling tens or hundreds of items a night.

Cutting open chicken to see if it is done and no longer pink in the middle is not a dependable way to tell if it's fully cooked or not, because sometimes chicken actually turns red or pink as it is being cooked.  So the only way to know absolutely for sure is to get a meat thermometer.  I know that's not what you want to hear, because if you're like me you are asking this question as you are cooking and do not have the time to run and get a thermometer at the store.  I would go ahead and order one for future use.  They're super cheap online and really worth having in your kitchen.  If you are currently cooking and, in a hurry, then what I would do is my best to eyeball the center of the pieces of chicken for doneness.  Unfortunately, because placement of meat on a grill, stove, etcetera, can cook meat at different speeds, you will have to cut open and check each individual piece.  It's not worth the risk of food poisoning to skip this step.
